# Kendo UI hierarchy grid css styling questions

Tags: kendo-grid

I'm working on a multi-level Kendo UI Hierarchy grid, and actually trying to make it look a bit like the jqwidgets treegrid (i.e. [jQWidgets Grid](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxtreegrid/index.htm) )

For one thing, I've managed to use CSS to get rid of the col headers using this css:

```
   #detailGrid1 > div.k-grid-header > div > table > thead {
        display: none;
   }
```

Now I'd like to supress the box around each child grid. Or perpahs just removing the left-most vertical border at the n-level child grid.

Any css advice would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You just want the border to not show? Did you try settings its border to 0px?

Comment: I'll try that too. I did something but doesn't look clean in my grid.